# how to lauch external application using hot key through vb.net

Tags: vb.net, winforms, keyboard-shortcuts

I have a windows program which is launched after pressing certain key combination (if its already running). Now i want to do this triggering through vb.net code? How can it be done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

check the following posting it shows you how:
http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/vssmartdevicesnative/thread/edb00219-530a-4506-acf1-0bea8e73a32d

Comment: Great link. But how to use it to send the multiple keys?

Answer (score 2):

You can do this by pinvoking RegisterHotKey.  Search this site or the web for that name to find sample code.  [Here's one](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/Vsexpressvb/thread/2622427d-1e15-4f30-b01d-57b0ba054f5c/) for example.

Do beware that this is probably not a good investment of your time, Windows already supports it.  Create a shortcut to the program.  Right-click it, Properties, Shortcut tab.  Click the "Shortcut key" text box and press the keystroke combination you want to use.

Comment: This is fine, but i would like to clarify more about question. I just want to trigger already launched application. And normally this triggering will be done through key combination (say Alt+Ctrl+a), so that application window becomes active and comes to front. So i want this to happen through code. Is sendkeys and option in vb.net to do this?

Answer (score 1):

You need to watch the keydown event on your form. I am including a link from the msdn on examples:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.keydown.aspx
here is a code snippet i found that someone posted:
http://www.daniweb.com/forums/thread114278.html

Comment: instead of detecting these key press combination i want to produce/ simulate this through vb.net code